# How to extract a particular string in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, extract

I have an **array:**

`users = ["employe es(123456)","admi ns(234567)","maste rs(098788)"/*,....*/];`

I want to extract this users for every index I have to return only:

`123456, 234567, 098788`

How can I do in **angular 5**?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular

Comment: If you want to get and array in the end, use the map operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference due to angular, just use js/ts usual code:

```js
let users = ["employes(123456)","admins(234567)","masters(098788)"];

let result = users.map(e => e.replace(/[a-z]/g, ''));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex` , this is replace your string in to blank

```
array.map(a => a.replace(/[a-z]/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this with default JavaScript string manipulation:

```
users.forEach(myStripFunction);

function myStripFunction(str) {
   var subString = str.slice(str.indexOf("("), str.length); 
   console.log(subString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let list= users.map(e => e.replace(/[a-z()''\sA-Z]/g, ''));
```